# SQL logic for More than 1 event date with at least 1 month between those event dates

Tags: sql, date, logic

I, a newbie, have a question about the SQL date logic for querying the following data set:
[Person, Event, Date]

[image: 1]

I need to identify the person who had events happened more than once with at least 1 month between those event dates. I used the following logic:

```
; with cte as ( select Person, Event, Date
                from data )  
select c1.Person, max(c1.Date) as maxdate, min(c2.Date) as mindate, datediff (month, min(c2.Date), max(c1.Date)) as MonthDiff
from cte c1
left outer join cte c2
on c1.Date > c2.Date
and c1.Person = c2.Person
where MonthDiff >1 and MonthDiff is not null 
group by c1.Person, c1.Date
```

MonthDiff is not null for those More than 1 event date
MonthDiff > 1 for those  with at least 1 month between those event dates

Just want to make sure the logic is right and if there is any better scripts without using CTE?

TIA

chichi

Comment: tag your database as well

Comment: Sorry about the newbie's question. How to tag a database?

Answer (score 0):

the better way is to use the partition. this code is better and simple. use this.

```
SELECT tb.Person,tb.[Date],datediff (month, tb.FirstDate, tb.Date) as MonthDiff
FROM (
SELECT t0.Person,t0.[Date],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t0.Person ORDER BY t0.Person,t0.[Date])ROWNUMBER,
MIN(t0.[Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY t0.Person)FirstDate
FROM Table1 t0) tb
WHERE datediff (month, tb.FirstDate, tb.Date)>0
```